# Filter list of rows based on a column value in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list of rows after using collect. How can I get the "num_samples" value where sample_label == 0? That is to say, how can I filter list of rows based on a column value?

```
[Row(sample_label=1, num_samples=14398),
 Row(sample_label=0, num_samples=12500),
 Row(sample_label=2, num_samples=98230]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible answers to your question is list comprehension:

```
data = [Row(sample_label=1, num_samples=14398),
 Row(sample_label=0, num_samples=12500),
 Row(sample_label=2, num_samples=98230)]

filtered_data = [row.num_samples for row in data if row.sample_label == 0]
```

EDIT: as @RomanPerekhrest is saying, filter before you collect. Why? [As per documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.collect.html):

> This method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to
> be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s memory.

Collect the data only when you are absolutely sure that you really need the collected data in such a format. If you do, heavily filter the data to lower the chances of a driver node failing with an OOM exception.

Answer (score 2):

Filter dataframe rows on the needed condition before collecting them:

`df.filter(df.sample_label == 0).collect()`